# How to initialize terminal manually?

Tags: jquery-terminal

how may i log stuff into the terminal before the user focuses the terminal and presses enter key?

I cannot find a way to access the echo method of the terminal outside a call function scope.

The "greetings" option is good but it does not help, i am trying to use the terminal to show the logs of a background application that is constantly running.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, by setting the "terminal" method to a variable it actually returns the created terminal (as a constructor).

Took me a while to find out, maybe because i don't have much experience with JScript and it has some different concepts about variable access, inheritance, etc.. than other languages.

Now i can store the created terminal and use it right after creation:

```
$(function () {
    var terminal;

    terminal = $('#consolediv').terminal(function(command, term) {
        if (command !== '') {
            interp.eval(command);
        } else {
            term.echo('');
        }
    }, { greetings: false });

    terminal.echo("logging and using terminal right after creation");
});
```